# How to get a value-only flat array from $wpdb->get_results when selecting a single column, without foreach()?

Tags: wpdb

My query is:

```
$var = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT field FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table", ARRAY_A);
var_dump($var);
```

it returns someting like array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["field"]=> string(5) "test1" } [1]=> array(1) { ["field"]=> string(t) "test2" }. I.e. each item is a row with a single name-value pair.

What I want is array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "test1" [1]=> string(5) "test2" }

Currently I achieve it like this:

```
$var = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT field FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table");
foreach($var as $v_key => $v_val) $var[$v_key] = $v_val['field'];
var_dump($var);
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is.

If you want to retrieve just one column from the database table, i.e. all row values for that column, you can use [`wpdb::get_col()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/).

```php
$values = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT field FROM {$wpdb->prefix}table" );
foreach ( $values as $value ) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Sally! Can't wait for my reputation to allow me to upvote your answers )